# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string[]>'

Tags: c#, hashset

I have two hashsets. One consist of list of string and the other one is list of string array.

```
HashSet<string> hashSetpdf = new HashSet<string>();
var hashSetReports = new HashSet<string[]>(DTtoList(dReport));
```

So I'm trying to search a string from hashSetpdf to the first index of all the elements of hashSetReports.

actually, I have the below code all running good but my problem is, it takes so much time if I have a lot of data.

```
        foreach (string c in hashSetpdf)
        {
            if (hashSetReports.Any(r => r.Contains(c)))
            {
                //do something...
            }
            else
            {
                //do something...
            }
        }
```

I tried the below but it is giving me an error.

```
        foreach (string c in hashSetpdf)
        {
            if (hashSetReports.Contains(c))
            {
                //do something...
            }
            else
            {
                //do something...
            }
        }
```

This is the error I encountered.

```
Error   5   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string[]>'
```

Is there any fast way for searching on the first index of string array in hashset?

Comment: Rather than a hashset of string arrays, have you considered an array of string hashsets? Or a hashset of string hashsets?

Comment: Without a custom comparer, I'm not sure `HashSet<string[]>` does what you expect anyway. See [this example](https://rextester.com/IHXCY34441) and [this example](https://rextester.com/TGJT74776). Unless you pass the exact same _array instance_, [`Contains` will return `false`](https://rextester.com/RJAZM95758).

Answer (score 0):

So you have a set of strings (call it A), and you want to check if, in a set of a list of strings (call the set B), any of the strings in any of the lists in this set has a string in your set of strings (A).

This will necessarily take |A| * \sum_i |B| * n_i time, where n_i is the length of the i'th list in set B, and |X| indicates the cardinality of X.